# Sort array of objects with unknown keys javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do I sort an array with objects and I don't known what are the keys in the objects. Here is the sample array, also note the field 'updatedAt'. Lodash solution would be greatly appreciated, but not necessary though. Kindly help.

```
let arrayToSort = [
        {
            fromDate: "2018-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",             
            toDate: "2018-03-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            updatedAt: new Date("2016-08-17T20:21:08.723Z"),
            createdAt: "2016-08-17T20:21:08.723Z"
        },
        {
            fromDate: "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            toDate: "2017-12-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            updatedAt: "2016-06-28T21:20:21.754Z",
            createdAt: "2016-06-28T21:20:21.754Z",
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is your sort criteria. You need to sort on some value ??

Comment: This is so fckg unclear, what you are trying to sort, based on all values?

Comment: @webdeb `fckg` - not a very pleasant word to use on SO ! :P

Comment: How would you know which object comes before which in the sorted array?

Comment: You can't sort by unknown keys...makes absolutely no sense